# Android OpenGL-ES: Object is showing up with wrong Chirality

Tags: android, opengl-es, projection-matrix

I have an object that I am rendering in Android OpenGL ES 3.0, on a Nexus 9. The object has somewhere around 80000 vertices and a couple hundred thousand triangles.

I know for a fact that those vertices are in a Right-handed coordinate system. When I use my pc to view the object (using a program like Paraview), I see the object in a right-handed coordinate system. But as soon as I render the object on my app in OpenGL, the object has the wrong chirality.

As I mentioned above, I'm pretty certain that my vertices are correct. Therefore, something wrong must be occurring during the coordinate transformations. Does anyone have any idea which matrix (view, model, projection) might be a likely source of my problem? I need to maintain the integrity of my vertices and not perform any transformations (like flipping values manually) on the vertex data itself.

**EDIT:** Someone asked for my code: I can't post everything because it is an incredibly large project, but I'll show you the lines where my matrices have been set up:

In onSurfaceCreated():

```
final float eyeX = 0.0f;
final float eyeY = 0.0f;
final float eyeZ = -3.0f;


final float lookX = 0.0f;
final float lookY = 0.0f;
final float lookZ = 0.0f;


final float upX = 0.0f;
final float upY = 1.0f;
final float upZ = 0.0f;


Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);        
Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix2, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);   
Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix3, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);   
Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix4, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);   `
```

In onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height):

```
    GLES30.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    viewport[0] = 0;
    viewport[1] = 0;
    viewport[2] = width;
    viewport[3] = height;

    final float ratio = (float) width / height;
    final float left = -ratio;
    final float right = ratio;
    final float bottom = -1.0f;
    final float top = 1.0f;
    final float near = 1.0f;
    final float far = 500.0f; 

    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix2, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix3, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix4, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
```

To clarify, the object that I am referring to uses mViewMatrix and mProjectionMatrix, not the other view matrices and projection matrices. If there isn't something wrong with this code, I can post more showing the places where I manipulated these matrices.

**EDIT2:** I simply do not understand why, but manually flipping coordinates (for instance, flipping the z-coordinate) either by changing the vertex data or by applying a scale matrix to the modelview, does not fix my chirality problem. I am absolutely stumped as to how to fix this.

Comment: You should show your code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out my problem (after 16 hours of trying). Turns out I was culling the wrong side. Switching from GL_BACK to GL_FRONT did the trick for me.